# macOS: Capture system audio and use it in Electron.js

Tags: audio, electron, core-audio, audio-capture

I Know this is a complex topic it is not possible directly in Electron.js on macOS.

I am looking for any solution where I can achieve it is using a virtual device or a aggregate device but we should be able to control it programmatically.

I have seen a few applications that are achieving it by creating aggregate/virtual device and then set that device as system default audio output when the application is in use and later restore it to the default settings.

I tried to create my own Version of [Blackhole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) but it dose not appear in my system as a new device after installation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ScreenCaptureKit has options for capturing device audio -- that's probably the easiest path at this point